Conversation Summarization Reduce Expiration Time
With the Azure Cognitive Service for Conversation Summarization.
When calling it using REST API, I wonder if there is a way to reduce the expiration time for the result.
In the JSON result example, it shows the "expirationDateTime" for 1 day since you submitted it:
{
  "jobId": "02ec5134-78bf-45da-8f63-d7410291ec40",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-09-29T17:43:02Z",
  "createdDateTime": "2022-09-29T17:43:01Z",
  "expirationDateTime": "2022-09-30T17:43:01Z",
  "status": "succeeded",

But I was thinking to reduce its time, to reduce the Azure Speech cost.
Thank you!
